# cron commands do not run, getting output /bin/sh: 1: php: not found

Tags: php, cron

I have the following inside my `crontab -e`

```
0,30 * * * * cd /usr/local/bin && php /var/www/artisan my_command > /var/www/storage/logs/cron.log 2>&1
```

But I get the following inside `/var/www/storage/logs/cron.log`.

```
/bin/sh: 1: php: not found
```

I tried running the following for reference:

```
# which php
/usr/local/bin/php
# whoami
root
```

I am running cron from inside a docker image (OS: Ubuntu) in a Laravel project.
I tried changing the path in different ways, but it still gave the same error.
There were a lot of similar questions, but I didn't manage to find my answer...

Comment: The current directory isn't in your `PATH` (and it shouldn't be). Simply skip the useless `cd` command and run `/usr/local/bin/php` instead.

Comment: @ Some programmer dude Wow, just like that it worked... If you add your comment as an answer I can set it as the correct answer.

Comment: @Some programmer dude 's solution works great. But basically the PHP command alone can be used but it all depends on the PHP installation

Comment: @Juan I am working on a Laravel project started by someone else, so I am unsure as to how I should change the installation method... Could adding ```/usr/local/bin``` inside the ```PATH``` have the same effects as to changing the installation method?

Comment: @TheBlindHawk I misspoke. In fact it does not depend on the installation of PHP but on the presence of "**/usr/local/bin**" in the PATH of the user launching the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current directory isn't in the `PATH` ([and it shouldn't be](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part2/section-13.html)).

Simply skip the useless `cd` command and run `/usr/local/bin/php` instead:

```
0,30 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/artisan my_command > /var/www/storage/logs/cron.log 2>&1
```

Comment: "_The current directory is not in the PATH_". It is not the current directory that we want to have in the PATH but the directory /usr/local/bin/. Which is a variable of a PATH in some installations it seems to me..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Some programmer dude.
I would like to add some details, since I was not originally able to understand what he meant.
Basically when I was calling `php` cron would look for the file in every folder inside the `PATH`, but NOT the current directory (unless it is inside the `PATH`).
Sure, simply removing the cd is the best solution.
But to better explain the issue another perfectly working solution would be this one:

```
0,30 * * * * cd /usr/local/bin && ./php /var/www/artisan my_command
```

The only difference here, from the command I was originally using, is that I am specifying to use the current path with the `./`.